# The range of the function $f(x)=\cot^{-1}\left\{-x\right\}+\sin^{-1}\left\{x\right\}++\cos^{-1}\left\{x\right\}$

Tags: calculus, functions

What is the range of the function $f(x)=\cot^{-1}\left\{-x\right\}+\sin^{-1}\left\{x\right\}++\cos^{-1}\left\{x\right\}$,where $\left\{.\right\}$ denotes the fractional part function.
Here $\cot^{-1}$ is an arccotangent function,$\sin^{-1}$ is an arcsine function,$\cos^{-1}$ is a arccosine function.

---

I know that the value of $\left\{x\right\},\left\{-x\right\}$ varies from $[0,1)$.So the domain of given $f(x)$ is $[0,1)$.But i could not find the the range of this function.Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

$\implies\sin^{-1}\left\{x\right\}++\cos^{-1}\left\{x\right\}=\dfrac\pi2$

$\implies f(x)=\pi-\tan^{-1}\{x\}$

Now $0\le\{x\}<1\implies0\le \tan^{-1}\{x\}<\dfrac\pi4$